# Как оптимизировать запрос на количество значений в столбцах таблицы на сотни млн. строк?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, pgadmin4

Как я могу оптимизировать запрос для того, чтобы получить количество значений в столбцах таблицы?

Мой запрос сейчас выглядит вот так:

```
SELECT count('col1'), [...] count('col25')
FROM scheme.table
```

Правилен ли он, можно ли его как-нибудь оптимизировать или переписать как-то совсем иначе?

Проблема в том, что предположительно в таблице, с которой я работаю 158 млн. строк и я боюсь, что выполняться это будет просто до моей смерти.

Comment: что такое "количество значений в столбцах таблицы" ?

Comment: по факту count('column'), но для всех столбцов

Comment: А что вы такое делаете и зачем такое нужно?

Comment: По факту нужно вытащить количество значений столбцов, количество уникальных значений, количество пропусков в столбцах и прочее-прочее, что в том же питоне можно сделать через pandas-profiling, но к сожалению я сейчас имею дело именно с sql

Comment: А нельзя всю вот эту статистику хранить отдельно и перестраивать триггерами? Ну, типа, если данных много, но апдейтятся они редко?

Comment: Если бы я был админом этой таблицы, может, после вашего комментария я бы поискал в нужном направлении...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам подойдет **приблизительная** статистика, которую можно найти в [таблице `pg_stats`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/view-pg-stats.html):

```
select * 
from pg_stats
where schemaname='<your_schema_name>'
  and tablename='<your_table_name>'
```

Можно попробовать создать индексы для не-строковых столбцов и сравнить план выполнения запроса с индексами и без них. Но делать это нужно аккуратно - иногда создание индекса может навредить. Особенно это актуально для таблиц, в которые часто пишут, т.к. при записи PostgreSQL придется обновлять индексы.

---

PS можно еще конечно помечтать о [columnstore](https://swarm64.com/post/postgresql-columnstore-index-intro/), но судя по комментариям, у вас нет прав админа.

Answer (score 1):

> нужно вытащить количество значений столбцов, количество уникальных значений, количество пропусков в столбцах и прочее-прочее

```sql
SELECT 'col1' column_name, 
       count(col1) cnt, 
       count(distinct col1) cnt_distinct, 
       count(col1) - count(distinct col1) cnt_null
FROM scheme.table

UNION ALL
-- ...

SELECT 'colN' column_name, 
       count(colN) cnt, 
       count(distinct colN) cnt_distinct, 
       count(colN) - count(distinct colN) cnt_null
FROM scheme.table
```

Для оптимизации каждого отдельного подзапроса по `colX` необходимо наличие индекса по этому полю. Но куча индексов по отдельным полям непременно скажется отрицательным образом на запросах модификации данных.